# Get Sum of Required Values in DataTable VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datatable

I have a datatable with the following fields:

- Day
- Date
- Room Rate
- No of Person
- Amount

The data is as follows:

```
Day Date    Room No.    Room Rate   No. of Person       Amount
1   4/9/2018    101         900.00      2           1, 800.00
2   4/10/2018   101         900.00      2           1, 800.00
3   4/10/2018   101         900.00      2           1, 800.00
1   4/9/2018    102         1000.00     3           3, 000.00
2   4/10/2018   102         1000.00     3           3, 000.00
3   4/10/2018   102         1000.00     3           3, 000.00
```

I would like to get the total amount by getting the sum of Amount. But, the last day for each Room should not be included. With the above example, the total amount would be 9, 600.00 since Room 101 and Room 102 of day 3 is not included.

I tried to use the datatable compute function, but this will not be effective:

```
Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables("dt_Lodging").Compute("SUM(Amount)", "Day = 3")
```

Day will not be limited to 3. If we have days 1 to 5, day 5 is the one which will not be included in Total.

Comment: Firstly, that's `DataTable.Compute`, not `BindingSource.Compute`. Secondly, why would it not be effective? The purpose of the `Compute` method is to evaluate aggregate functions with an optional filter, which is exactly what you're trying to do. You just need to provide the correct filter. Don't hard-code the day number but rather get the value from the `DataTable`. That sounds like a job for the `MAX` function, which is another aggregate. I wonder how you execute aggregate functions.

Comment: Given that the `BindingSource` class has no `Compute` method, it would be fairly difficult to call it.  Why do you think that indexing the `Tables` collection of a `DataSet` would return a `BindingSource`?

Comment: I've already told you everything you need to know. You just need to think more than one step at a time. Get all the room numbers, call `Compute` for each one to get the max day value, build a filter that excludes those days (you can use as many AND and OR operators as you like) then call `Compute` again with that filter to sum the amounts.

Comment: just modifed my question. It is DataTable.Compute. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try his line

```
Dim Amount As Decimal = T.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).GroupBy(Function(X) CStr(X("RoomNo"))).Sum(Function(Room) Room.Take(Room.Count - 1).Sum(Function(X) pDec(X("Amount"))))
```

But your question is not clear abount name of RoomNo column. And the query has some presumptions according to your question.
It will not work when the room number repeats in different periods. Or when the rows are not sorted by date.

This solution is not optimized in any way. It just calculates the value.

Does room rate vary by date? Room rate*Number of nights would be better solution. You should work with nights of stay instead of days anyway.

**EDIT:** 
Full code version

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim R As DataRow, i As Integer
    Using T As New DataTable
        T.Columns.Add("RoomNo", GetType(String))
        T.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))
        For i = 1 To 3
            R = T.NewRow
            R("RoomNo") = "101"
            R("Amount") = 1800
            T.Rows.Add(R)
            R = T.NewRow
            R("RoomNo") = "102"
            R("Amount") = 3000
            T.Rows.Add(R)
        Next
        Dim Amount As Decimal = T.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).GroupBy(Function(X) CStr(X("RoomNo"))).Sum(Function(Room) Room.Take(Room.Count - 1).Sum(Function(X) CDec(X("Amount"))))
        Debugger.Break()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: room rate does not vary by date. Room Rate * Number of Nights will do. However, in the example above, day 3 should be still visible.

Comment: @Pavlinll , I tried yor code but the result is zero. 

       `Dim pDec() As Decimal` 
       `Dim Amount As Decimal = T.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).GroupBy(Function(X) CStr(X("RoomNo"))).Sum(Function(Room) Room.Take(Room.Count - 1).Sum(Function(X) pDec(X("Amount"))))`


I am new in using Linq. What is the use of variable pDec?

Comment: I'm sorry, use CDec() instead of pDec().

Comment: By using this code, `Room.Take(Room.Count - 1)`, 
the result will be zero. But when i disregard the '-1', it sums up all amount inlcuding the last record of each group.

Comment: .Take(Room.Count - 1) is removing the last day from that group. I've updated the answer to provide full code and there's expected 9600 value in Amount variable. Inspect result of T.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).GroupBy(Function(X) CStr(X("RoomNo"))) to see details.

Comment: I've got it withs:

`Dim result = BookingDataSet.Tables("dt_Lodging").AsEnumerable() _
                        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("RoomNo")) _
                        .Select(Function(grp) New With _
                         { _
                        .RoomNo = grp.Key, _
                        .TotalAmt = grp.Take(grp.Count - 1).Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("Amount")) _
                        }) _
                         .Sum(Function(x) x.TotalAmt)`

This is almost similar with your first code. Your code works too.
Thank you!

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted please. Creating the New With {} intermediate object is unecessary overhead but it should work almost the same. One more tip: You do not need to put underscores in your syntax to make new lines - just leave the dot at the end of the line and start with GroupBy on new line. Compiler will handle that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#implicit-line-continuation